# Determine whether or not the set given is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let W = {x ∈ R<sup>3</sup>} satisfying the equations x<sub>1</sub> = 3x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>2</sub> = −4x<sub>3</sub>.

In another problem similar to this, given by

> > Let W = {x ∈ R<sup>3</sup>} satisfying the equation x<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub> = x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub>

I found that the set is not a subspace. I'm not quite sure how to find if two equations are closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Look up the definition of a [subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition); you should find a description of a condition that a set must satisfy to be a subspace. Check that $W$ (the set of vectors $x$ satisfying the two equations) satisfies the conditions.

Comment: I suppose I didn't convey my question properly. What I'm trying to understand is how to find if it is a subspace when given two equations. I've done one problem already from the homework but it only had one equation.